# Revealing output slowly in Magma

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

When working in Magma, is there a command to gradually reveal the output. For example, if you have a finite group $G$ and you want to calculate **SubgroupLattice(G)**, then the output may be thousands of lines long. Is there a way to reveal the output one page at a time?

Comment: Commenting just to get notifs for this thread. Wish to close this tab on Firefox. Perhaps not best use of comments, but I know of no other way. Hope you get response for this :).

Comment: You can redirect magma output into a file, and that's probably the best way to go when the output is large. This is described in the handbook.